# is this txt file actually an image?

Tags: java, image, neural-network, image-classification

I found this GitHub rep about image classification (Male and female images) using an artificial neural network, the training data are 2 directories "./male", and "./female", each one contains a list of txt files.

these text files contain rows of numbers, each row of 16 numbers.
a preview

```
37 40 48 49 49 45 41 34 34 34 33 34 33 33 33 33
32 31 31 31 30 30 29 29 28 27 28 27 27 26 26 26
25 25 24 24 24 23 23 22 22 21 21 20 20 19 19 19
18 19 20 21 25 25 24 22 16 17 15 22 21 20 21 20
20 20 19 19 19 16 20 21 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 24
24 24 25 24 24 25 26 25 25 26 26 25 26 26 26 26
27 27 27 28 28 29 29 29 29 30 29 29 29 29 29 29
29 30 29 29 30 30 30 30 30 30 29 29 29 29 28 29
...
```

I don't understand! ARE THESE SUPPOSED TO BE IMAGES (matrices of pixels values)?

the rep link:
https://github.com/Kurispy/neuralnet

Comment: Looks a bit like an ASCII ("plain" or P2) PGM file without header...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By investigating the source code of Main.java we see that files are intended to be **painted** https://github.com/Kurispy/neuralnet/blob/master/Main.java#L90

```
public static void painter(FileInputStream fin) {
double[] store = new double[120 * 128];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(15360 + 1) * 8];
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
    DoubleBuffer db = b.asDoubleBuffer();
    
    try {
        while(fin.available() > 0) {
            fin.read(buffer, 0, (15360 + 1) * 8);
        
            
            db.get();
            db.get(store);
            db.rewind();
            paint(store);
        }
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    
}
```

and we see that each file is interpreted as 120 x 128 grayscale image, by loading first file and trying to plot it like this we see it is a picture of a face.[image]

Comment: thank you so much, that was really helpful

Answer (score -1):

Yes the files contain grayscale images. It is obvious when you look at the actual code.

Comment: While your answer may be factually correct, it is distinctly unhelpful. The whole reason a person asks a question is because it is indeed, NOT obvious to them.  To be helpful, your answer needs to show them what you see, so that it's obvious to them too.